# How to map XMS messages onto IBM MQ messages

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, xms

I have a windows service subscribing to a IBM MQ using the traditional amqmdnet.dll and the publishing application is using IBM.XMS library. When my subscriber reads the messages, its failing to de-serializing the JMS styles message.

I tried a sample application using IBM.XMS dlls and the de-serializing worked perfectly fine.

Is there a way to successfully translate JMS style message to IBM MQMessage? I tried reading few articles here, but I did not complete understand how to proceed?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_rmes_maptowmq.htm

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/rjc0005_.html

Comment: What is the content of the messages, is it just string data?

Comment: its byte[]. We are using Google protocol buffers as well

Comment: Is the issue just the RFH2 headers on the message when read by the traditional amqmdnet.dll?  Can you confirm which version of amqmdnet.dll you are using?

Comment: amqmdnet.dll version is 8.0.0.0. I am not sure what exactly the issue is. When I deserialize the mesage with amqmdnet.dll it fails and with IBM.XMS it succeeds.

Comment: Can you post sample code that deserializes the message both working (IBM.XMS) and non-working (amqmdnet)?